# JavaScript Grocery List

Tags: javascript, arrays, add-in

I am trying to create a groceryList program. Right now, I'm just working on some basic functions. Adding an item to my grocery list, removing an item from grocery list, viewing the grocery list, and also marking if I have picked the item up. I am stuck on how I can get the 'marking' function to work properly, here is my code:

```
var groceryList = [];

function add_item(item){
    groceryList.push(item);
}

function remove_item(item){
    for (var i = 0; i <= groceryList.length; i++){
        if (groceryList[i] === item) groceryList.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

function view_list(){
    for (var i = 0; i < groceryList.length; i++){
        if (groceryList.length == 0)
        return;
        else
        console.log("- " + groceryList[i]);
    }
}

function mark_item(item){
    for (var i = 0; i <= groceryList.length; i++){
        if (groceryList[i] == item) console.log("X " + groceryList[i]);
    }
}

view_list();
add_item('banana');
add_item('apple');
view_list();
add_item('testies');
view_list();
remove_item('testies');
view_list();
mark_item('apple');
```

Obviously when I run the `mark_item` function it just prints the item I put in with an `X` next to it. I'm wondering if someone has suggestions on how I can approach this?

Comment: May be you can have one more array for storing the marked items.

Comment: u can use here 2D array in my given example

Answer (score 4):

You are moving from being able to store your items as simple strings to needing to store some contextual data about your items as well, ie whether you've marked them or not. You can start storing your items as javascript objects with a name and a marked flag.

```
function add_item(item){
    groceryList.push({
        name: item, 
        marked: false
    });
}
function view_list(){
    for (var i = 0; i < groceryList.length; i++){
        if (groceryList.length == 0)
        return;
        else
        // let's display marked off items differently 
        if (groceryList[i].marked){
            console.log("X " + groceryList[i].name);
        } else {
            console.log("- " + groceryList[i].name);
        }

    }
}
function mark_item(item){
    for (var i = 0; i <= groceryList.length; i++){
        if (groceryList[i].name == item) {
            // when we mark an item, we just set its flag
            groceryList[i].marked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this solution. Makes complete sense too. I'm pretty new so these things don't come to mind at first. After you mentioned it I was thinking....'Of course, why didn't I think of that!'. Anyways, I have adjusted my code, yet I'm still getting an error with `groceryList[i].name == item`. The error is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. Any ideas? Also, do you know why questions like mine get down votes? I have no clue why I get them? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is that happening in your remove_item function? Try wrapping that splice call in a set of curly braces and adding a return; inside there as well. After you've found the item to remove, you don't need to do the rest of the loop, right?

Comment: No idea why you got downvoted. The downvoter ought to note why they did it.

Comment: The error comes when trying to use the `mark_item` function. I'm going to play around with it some more. IDK why it cannot read the property name and it thinks its undefined...It is clearly in my list.

Comment: That error is saying that the groceryList[i] is undefined. Is there a typo?

Comment: The error was with the `for` loop. I had `i` set to `<=` and it works when I change it to just `<` without the `=`. Idk exactly why, but I'll do more research on that.