# What is the most efficient way to make 100+ counters?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering what is the most efficient way to put potentially 100+ counters(like this - https://mp-counter.netlify.app/) for a grocery list website in vanilla JS

I want to add a feature where a user can press "+" or "-" to add or subtract the quantity they want

for example - Rice - 0 + KG
If i press + it should increase the number and - should decrease the number

Comment: Use an array of Javascript objects.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30295726/102937) should provide you with some decent ideas to get started.

Comment: No. I am fetching the items from a third party api

Comment: Then the data should already be in a suitable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short snippet that will create 100 counters and buttons to increase or decrease their content:

```js
const cont=document.getElementById('container');
cont.addEventListener('click',ev=>{
  if (ev.target.tagName!=="BUTTON") return;
  let cntr=ev.target.parentNode.querySelector('span');
  cntr.textContent = +cntr.textContent + (ev.target.textContent=="+"?1:-1)
});
cont.innerHTML=
  [...Array(100).keys()].map(i=>
  `<div><button>-</button><span>0</span><button>+</button> ${i+1}</div>`)
  .join('\n')
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

I make use of "delegated event listening" in the way that I attach the click event to the parent `div#container`. Only when a `BUTTON` is clicked will the event function do something: dependent on the clicked button it will add either `1` or `-1` to the current value of the neighboring `span` element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about efficiency but the simpliest is an element for the quantity and 2 bottons.

```js
const quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
const plus = document.getElementById('plus');
const minus = document.getElementById('minus');

plus.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    quantity.innerText = parseInt(quantity.innerText) + 1;
});

minus.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    quantity.innerText = Math.max(0, parseInt(quantity.innerText) - 1);
});
```

```html
<button id="minus">Minus</button>
<span id="quantity">0</span>
<button id="plus">Plus</button>
```

In this case we add (and subtract) one by one, If you want to go 100+ you may think about implementing a way to go faster.